# FT2232H Compatible Oscillator (SiT2024B?)

Tags: circuit-design

I've got a board with an FT2232H and 12 MHz SiT2024B with drive strength 'L' running at 3.3 Volts. It does not appear to be working properly. The FTDI chip does not appear in the FT_PROG scan. Is the SiT2024B capable of driving the FT2232H if the default drive strength were used, or do I need to find a different solution for the oscillator?

FTDI would only say that the oscillator has to be USB High Speed compatible, and run at 12 MHz +/- 30 ppm. The SiT2024B looks like it should be able to handle this task, but I may be mistaken.

Comment: That drive mode is pretty light, but I can't find the input capacitance or max rise/fall times for the FT2232H.  OSCO will likely output an amplified version of OSCI.  You could also probe OSCI directly, but a weak signal will get even weaker with the probe capacitance.

Comment: Apparently OSCI has to be VCCIO/2 or about 1.65V. I'm thinking a voltage divider is my friend here since the oscillator is 3.3V. Is that a train wreck in the making?

Comment: Where did you find that information? In the datasheet, it says 3-3.6V on OSCI. I don't think drive strength should be an issue since the chip is usually driving a crystal.

Comment: Never mind, works just fine.